# I want to find difference between two presenters salary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
Presenters(pre_name, salary)
```

Suppose I have the following values

```
Values ( 'A', 8 )
       ( 'B', 6 )
       ( 'C', 7 )
```

I want the following results

```
Pre-name    pre-name    salary-diff
A                    B                     2
A                   C                      1
B                   C                     -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need something like

```
SELECT p1.pre_name,
       p2.pre_name,
       p1.salary - p2.salary AS "salary-deff"
FROM   Presenters p1
       JOIN Presenters p2
         ON p2.pre_name > p1.pre_name;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PLFX59676)